# Database.database().reference() is nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating an iMessage app that needs to connect to the same database as my regular app.

I call FirebaseApp.configure() and I authenticate the user but for some reason after all of that Database.database().reference() is null even though it is supposed to be a non null value.

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
        print("FIREAPP Configed")
        print(FirebaseApp.app())
        signIn() //Use kept google credentials to log in
        configureDatabase()
    }
}

func configureDatabase() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    print(ref)
}
```

I'm expecting Database.database().reference() to be the root reference of the database instead of nil. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also struggling with similar errors.

In my situation, my understanding of CocoaPods was not enough.

Before:

```
target 'MyApp' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Database'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MyFrameWorkA' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  target 'MyFrameWorkB' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

 end
```

After:

```
abstract_target 'AnyTargets' do # Anything that doesn't duplicate the actual target name

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase/Database'

  target 'MyApp' do
  end

  target 'MyAppTests' do
  end

  target 'MyFrameWorkA' do
  end

  target 'MyFrameWorkB' do
  end

 end
```

I was able to consult your questions when looking for a solution.

I hope you solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed it was a problem with my code but you were right. When I changed my podfile to this it worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're confused about this line:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

This merely sets up a reference to the root of the database. It doesn't load any data yet.

To actually load the data, attach a listener to the reference:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value)
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

*Note that data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Any code that needs the data, must be **inside** the completion handler (as above) or be called from there.*

Also see the Firebase documentation on [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was able to narrow it downtime problem a little more. I do have ref.observe for .childChanged but for some reason the url of ref is empty. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over this error as well and the solution for me was adding 'Firebase/Core' to my pod file. I am not sure if this is common knowledge, but on setting up my firebase database project I never read about adding this specific pod.
My pod file after rewriting it:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  # add pods for desired Firebase products
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods

  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```